# Testing with sessions in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, session

Accoring to documentation I'm trying to mock session in my PHPUnit test:

```
public function testAction()
{
    $session = new Session(new MockArraySessionStorage());
    $session->set('abc', 'xyz');
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->getContainer()->set('session', $session);
    $client->request('GET', '/');
}
```

And in my controller I trying to get session value:

```
public function mainAction()
{
    $session = $this->get('session');
    var_dump($session->get('abc'), $session->all());die; //returns null and []
}
```

Why this stuff doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's because the session is resolved with the cookie, and you don't set the cookie who link the session to the client.

You should add:

```
    $client->getCookieJar()->set(new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId()));
```

There is a full example to log in a user:

```
    $session = $this->_container->get('session');
    $user = $this->_em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
                      ->findOneByEmail($email);
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
    $session->set('_security_<security_context>', serialize($token));
    $session->save();
    $client->getCookieJar()->set(new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId()));
```

Hope it help